# Maple: Add labels to specific points on a plot

Tags: plot, label, maple

I have a plot with a bunch of horizontal and vertical lines around the origin. I would like to  mark points along these lines; how would I go about doing this.

```
restart: V:= z -> LambertW(0, z)-LambertW(-1, z)
Vp := (x, y)-> (Re(V(x+I*y)), Im(V(x+I*y)));
zp :=  (x, y) -> (x,y);
plot ([zp(x,0), x=0..20],colour=[red]);
```

The code above generates one of the lines along the x-axis. I would like to add labels at say (5,0) or (0,0) and then do the same for the rest of the lines in my plot.

Answer (score 1):

You want command **plots:-textplot**.